# Xamarin: Combining DatePicker with TimePicker and storing as a string

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am a newbie to Xamarin. I have a form where users can create events. I am using datepicker and timepicker in the form. After doing my selections, the time value doesn't change if I pick date first and there are two time values for both labels [please refer to the picture]. But the biggest issue that the values get stored as null in backend database even I am storing them as a "string". Please help, this is very frustrating since couldn't find a hint/solution elsewhere. Thank you!

[This is how the label values are displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8Hf1.png)

This is my model:

```
[JsonProperty("EndDateTime")]
        public String StartDateTime { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("EndDateTime")]
        public String EndDateTime { get; set; }
```

This is my view:

```
<Label 
    Text="Start Date" 
    Grid.Row="0" 
    Grid.Column="0"
></Label>
<Label 
    Text="Finish Date" 
    Grid.Row="0" 
    Grid.Column="1"
></Label>
<DatePicker 
    Format="MMM dd, yyyy" 
    DateSelected="DatePicker_StartDateSelected" 
    Grid.Column="0" 
    Grid.Row="1" 
    MinimumDate="{x:Static system:DateTime.UtcNow}" 
/>
<DatePicker 
    Format="MMM dd, yyyy" 
    DateSelected="DatePicker_FinishDateSelected" 
    Grid.Column="1" 
    Grid.Row="1" 
    MinimumDate="{x:Static system:DateTime.UtcNow}" 
/>
<TimePicker 
    x:Name="StartTime" 
    Format="hh:mm" 
    Grid.Row="2" 
    Grid.Column="0" 
/>
<TimePicker 
    x:Name="EndTime" 
    Format="hh:mm" 
    Grid.Row="2" 
    Grid.Column="1" 
/>
<Label 
    x:Name="StartDate" 
    Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" 
    FontAttributes="Bold"  
    Text="{Binding StartDateTime, StringFormat='{}{0:MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm}'}" 
/>
<Label 
    x:Name="FinishDate" 
    Grid.Row="3" 
    Grid.Column="1" 
    FontAttributes="Bold"  
    Text="{Binding EndDateTime, StringFormat='{}{0:MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm}'}" 
/>
```

This is how I am concatenating datetime with time in code behind:

```
private void DatePicker_StartDateSelected(object sender, DateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    StartDate.Text = e.NewDate.Date.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " " + StartTime.Time.ToString();
}

private void DatePicker_FinishDateSelected(object sender, DateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    FinishDate.Text = e.NewDate.Date.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " " + EndTime.Time.ToString();
}
```

[And this is how it get stored in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyoFd.png)

Comment: Doesn't time TimePickers has an event when a time is selected too, that you should listen to? It seems like only update the StartDate and FinishDate labels when the dates changes.

Comment: @stiduck Thank you for your response. I am converting all of them into string in StartDate and FinishDate events ( + StartTime.Time.ToString()). But, even if I disregard TimePicker class, it sill sends out DateTime as null.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, giving a good thought, I realized that Labels' bindings do not propagate/store changes from the sources -DatePicker and Timepickers. So, only I had to do is change Labels bindings as  `Text="{Binding EndDateTime, Mode=TwoWay }"`

Set bindings as `Mode = TwoWay` did the trick :)